# Module constructor not loading

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a PrestaShop module and I'm having difficulties in showing the module name and description in the modules section in the backoffice.

The first time I've setup de module in the `modules/` directory it showed up fine, displaying the name, description, version and author correctly.

But after some changes to the code, now it just displays the name of the module directory and the icon inside. No matter what I do it just displays that information, even if I set the file as it was originally when everything showed up fine.

At first I thought it was a cache problem but after disabling all cache on `Advanced Parameters > Performance` it still displays only the directory name and icon file. I've also clicked in `Clear Cache` and nothing.

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class themegenerator extends Module
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'themegenerator';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Theme Generator');
        $this->description = $this->l('This is the Theme Generator description.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
        }
    }
}
```

I've also checked the file encoding (UTF-8), file permissions (644) and all seemed ok. I also have Debug Mode On but no error messages (apart from some translations Missing Messages).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the config*.xml files in the module directory ?

Those files store the module names and descriptions in order to display them faster in the modules tab.